# Javamail: Cannot get attachment from my university email service

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail, attachment, multipart

I am working on an android email client for my university email service. However, I have some troubles with attachments.Actually, I can get attachment from emails that are from gmail or other popular email services but I can't get attachments from emails that are from our university domain.

In gmail, it sends more than one body part in MimeMultipart (Message.getContent() returns MimeMultipart object) and I can get the attachments.

However, in my university email service  send one BodyPart in MimeMultipart and it has only the text part of the message as plain and html.

Should I use extra command for obtain attachments?

Answer (score 0):

This [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach) entry might help.

Also, try the [msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).  You can read the source code of the program to see it it finds the attachments, or you can use it with the "-s" option to show the structure of the message.  If you can't figure it out, post the -s output here.